# Как получить полную и свободную память телефона/SD карты в Android?

Tags: android

Я новичок в Android разработке, пишу файловый менеджер для Android. Мне необходимо реализовать возможность отображения состояния памяти телефона и SD-карты при ее наличии. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать это можно таким способом:

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
double sdAvailSize = (double)stat.getAvailableBlocks()
                   * (double)stat.getBlockSize();
//One binary gigabyte equals 1,073,741,824 bytes.
double gigaAvailable = sdAvailSize / 1073741824;
```

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941552/how-can-i-check-how-much-free-space-an-sd-card-mounted-on-an-android-device-has) еще и другие способы есть. Для получения полного размера можно воспользоваться таким [способом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834964/how-to-get-an-external-storage-sd-card-size-with-mounted-sd-card):

```
StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());        
 long blockSize = statFs.getBlockSize();
 long totalSize = statFs.getBlockCount()*blockSize;
 long availableSize = statFs.getAvailableBlocks()*blockSize;
 long freeSize = statFs.getFreeBlocks()*blockSize;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!!!